# How to add "targets in compile" to a SBT project which is defined with lazy val root = project.in(".")

Tags: scala, sbt, scalapb

I have a project:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings( ...
```

I wish to add ScalaPB to the project and I need to add:

```
PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
    scalapb.gen(grpc = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,
    scalapb.zio_grpc.ZioCodeGenerator -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,
)
```

How can I add this to the lazy val project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
      scalapb.gen(grpc = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,
      scalapb.zio_grpc.ZioCodeGenerator -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
    )
  )
```